# Writing to a property list on the iPod Touch not working but works in simulator

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipod-touch

In the application that I am writing I am trying to write a list of fortunes for a fortune cookie out to a property list. In the simulator this works as expected and everything is great. On the iPod Touch I have it reads from said list fine but it never updates the list.

Are there any differences between updating property lists using the simulator and using the iPod Touch?

```
    if(indexEdit == [data count])
    {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textField.text];
        [self.data addObject:temp];
    }
    else
    {
        NSString *temp = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", textField.text];
        [data replaceObjectAtIndex:indexEdit withObject:temp];
    }
    NSString *errorDesc;
    NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Fortunes"  ofType:@"plist"];
    NSData *plistData = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataFromPropertyList:data format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 errorDescription:&errorDesc];
    if (plistData)
    {
        [plistData writeToFile:bundlePath atomically:YES];
    }
    else 
    {
        NSLog(errorDesc);
        [errorDesc release];
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that your application bundle is considered to be pretty much read only. If you want to write a file you should put it in the "Documents" folder, something like:

```
NSArray *savePaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSMutableString *savePath = [NSMutableString stringWithString:[savePaths objectAtIndex:0]];
[savePath appendString:@"/Fortunes"];

// blah blah

[plistData writeToFile:savePath atomically:YES];
```

Comment: I had to say Fortunes.plist instead of Fortunes but it works. Thank you.

Comment: I'd do:   NSString *filename = [savePathstringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Fortunes.plist"];
  instead just so you do have to worry about slashes

Comment: Good point, Benny. In my defence I wrote that code when I first started learning Cocoa!